# Inner query comma separated results

Tags: sql, database

My Query is:

```
SELECT project_type_name FROM project_type WHERE project_type_id IN
(SELECT project_type_id FROM projects WHERE project_id = 93)
```

Where inner query returns 1 row with 3 comma separated values. (2,3,4). But outer query returns only 1 record only for 2.

Comment: And what's the problem? The sub-query returns 3 values, and then you search project_type for these values as project_type_id.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? But you shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column. Read up on database normalization

Comment: @jarlh, yes I am matching project_type_id with all those 3 values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using SQLyog currently for query testing. The db is already completed by DBA, I have to only fetch records as ML programmer :)

Comment: SQLyog  is not a DBMS, it's a SQL client.

Comment: DBA should know this is a 1NF violation. Get them to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use find_in_set for this purpose.

SELECT project_type_name
FROM project_type
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( project_type_id, (

SELECT project_type_id
FROM projects
WHERE project_id =93
) )

Answer (score 0):

You cannot treat a string of comma separated values like a list of values. In case the subquery returns *always* one row you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT project_type_name 
FROM project_type 
WHERE CONCAT(',', (SELECT project_type_id FROM projects WHERE project_id = 93), ',') 
      LIKE '%,' + project_type_id ',%'
```

Comment: That is invalid (standard) SQL. Please mention for which DBMS this works.

Comment: This worked for me. SELECT project_type_name
FROM project_type
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( project_type_id, (

SELECT project_type_id
FROM projects
WHERE project_id =93
) )

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos mySQL